# How can I get the button title for each selected cell in a UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView of buttons as pictured below. I want to be able to select multiple of these cells, and in doing so pass the title of each selected button into an array of Strings.

[UICollectionView - each cell has a button with a title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XDLF.png)

The UICollectionView is in WordViewController class

```
class WordViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

And the UICollectionViewCell is in it's own file.

```
import UIKit

class WordCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var wordView: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if wordView.isSelected == true {
        wordView.isSelected = false
        wordView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }else {
        wordView.isSelected = true
        wordView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }  
}

}
```

I'm very new to Swift and I have been trying to find an answer to this for days, but I can't figure it out. I suspect I may have to use indexPathsForSelectedItems but I have tried this and can't get it working.

```
func indexSelected () {
        let collectionView = self.collectionView
        let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
        print(indexPath!)
        let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath!) as? WordCollectionViewCell
        let data = cell?.wordView.currentTitle
        print(data!)

}
```

I'm not sure if I have something fundamental wrong in the way I have set up my CollectionView or if it is something to do with me using buttons within the CollectionViewCells.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: “suspect I may have to use indexPathsForSelectedItems but I have tried this and can't get it working” But in the code you have shown, you are NOT trying it. Please show an actual attempt.

Comment: Sorry, added my attempt to the question.

Comment: It's unclear from that, though, what you imagine would ever cause `indexSelected` to be called.

Comment: I have a button, which when clicked, calls indexSelected.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could do it. First get the indexPaths for the selected cells. Then loop through the indexPaths and get your cell for each IndexPath (cast them as your custom CollectionViewCell to access your button). Now you can append each title to an array to save them.

```
var titleArray = [String]()

    guard let selectedIndexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems else { return }

    for indexPath in selectedIndexPaths {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? WordCollectionViewCell {
            self.titleArray.append(cell.yourButton.titleLabel?.text)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This returns only the last selected cell - i.e. If I click on 4 cells, it will return the 4th cell I clicked on. How would i amend the code so that I could get the title of all four buttons? Sorry if this is a silly question - I'm very new to this.

Comment: I edited my original answer. You just have to create an array, when you loop through all your selected cells you can then append each title to the array.

Comment: I had tried something similar to this myself but getting the same result. I think I may have the collectionView set up incorrectly so that it doesn't allow multiple cell selection. Also, at the minute I am having to select the cell rather than the button inside the cell. Do you know if there is a way that I can select the cell by tapping on the button within the cell?

Comment: in your viewDidLoad do this to enable multiple selection: collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
It's hard to help you through StackOverflow comments, is there anywhere else I can reach you so I can help you out?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. This sounds a bit like an X/Y problem: A case where you are asking about how to implement a specific (often sub-optimal) solution rather than asking about how to solve the problem in the first place.

You should not treat the views in your collection view as saving data. (buttons are views.)

You should use the button to figure out the indexPath of the cell the user tapped and then look up the information in your data model.

You should set up an array of structs (or an array of arrays, if your collection view is in sections of rows.) Each of those structs should contain the current settings for a cell.

Your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method should use the array of structs to configure your sell for display.

As the user taps buttons and selects cells, you should update the struct(s) at the appropriate IndexPath(s) and then tell the collection view to update those cell.

If you need to do something with the selected cells, you should ask the collection view for an array of the selected cells, you should use those IndexPaths to index into your model array and fetch the struct for each IndexPath, and then look up teh data you need.

### EDIT:

You can use a really simple extension to UICollectionView to find the indexPath of any view inside your collection view (and a button is a view, as mentioned...)

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func indexPathForCellContaining( view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
        let viewCenter = self.convert(view.center, from: view.superview)
        return self.indexPathForItem(at: viewCenter)
    }
}
```